# React - ES6 - Dynamically watching the total character length of a textarea

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Please take a look at this [simple fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ilrein/Lz5v8gq9/).

It is a single react component, which is a textarea. It displays a counter below the textarea.

The goal is to have the counter update `onChange` to reflect the new value (total text area length).

Unfortunately, my counter dissappears whenever a change happens. I suspect my `this` or syntax is off specifically in the middle of this code block:

```
recalculate() {
  this.setState({
    text: this.state.text.length
  });
}
```

But React is a new beast and so is ES6. What am I missing here?

Comment: what does your initial state look like?

Comment: Accidentally put in the wrong link. Updated now. State is set with
this.state = { text: "hello from @merlo!" };

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should set `state` with new value, because now you always set default `state` value

```
recalculate(e) {
  this.setState({
     text: e.target.value
  });
}
```

[`Example`](https://jsfiddle.net/Lz5v8gq9/1/)

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is you rely on this.state.text to populate your textarea. Once you type and call recalculate() you change this.state.text to an int and then try and call .length on this int and this causes the value to be undefined. I would recommend this: https://jsfiddle.net/74jufckm/1/

```
recalculate( event ) {
 this.setState({
    text: event.target.value,
    textLength: event.target.value.length
 });
}
```

You were also never setting the state of the text again when recalculating.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with your recalculate function. You need to setState the new textarea value. Code like below should fix it

```
recalculate({target: {value}}) {
  this.setState({
    text: value
  });
}
```

[Here](https://jsfiddle.net/Lz5v8gq9/2/) is a JSfiddle with working code

Answer (score 1):

You want to update the value of the textbox. Try using `e.target.value` as the state.

https://jsfiddle.net/Lz5v8gq9/3/